# (Solved) Magento 2, Add product image in all transaction emails(shipment, invoice, credit memo)

Tags: magento2, product-images, transactional-mail

I have managed to add products images in new order email using this solution:
[Magento 2 product image in new order email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147762/magento-2-product-image-in-new-order-email)

Unfortunately this piece of code is not working for other transactional emails:

- credit memo
- new invoice
- new shipment

New Shipment email that i have received is showing error:

> " Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: _order in
>   /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Packers/luma/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/shipment/default.phtml
>   on line 12 "

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem();

$_order = $_item->getOrder();   //   -->  line 12
$_store = $_order->getStore();

/* product images */
$_imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$_baseImageUrl = $_store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product';



?>
<tr>
    <td>
         <img src="<?= $_imageHelper->init($_item->getProduct(), 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('150','150')->getUrl();?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
    </td>
```

Is there any solution for getting product images displayed on all transactional emails?

---

WORKING SOLUTION (for all transactional emails):

```
<?php

$_item = $block->getItem() 

$productId = $_item->getProductId();
$objectManagerHere = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManagerHere->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($product, 'category_page_list', array('height' => '100' , 'width'=> '100'))->getUrl();
?>

<img height="100" width="100" src="<?= $productImage ?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon in the first line. Try this...

```
/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem();  
$_order = $_item->getOrder();   
$_store = $_order->getStore();
```

Comment: Hey Harry, thanks for posting. I changed this and i can pass the admin view error.  But now email that i have received is showing error:   " Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: _order in /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Packers/luma/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/shipment/default.phtml on line 12 "