# Product Image in invoice email template

Tags: magento2, placeholder-image, sales-invoice

I am trying to get product images for invoice email template. I used below code. But I am only getting Magento placeholder image in email template.

```
<td>
    <?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product_id = $_item->getOrderItem()->getProduct();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

    $_imagehelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $image_url = $_imagehelper->init($product, 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->getUrl();

    ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
</td>
```

Comment: you can't use PHP in email templates

Comment: i did not use in my email template directly, i added this code in my file "Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/shipment/default.phtml"

Comment: Do you mean the order email?

Comment: Try the below answer and keep post your complete phtml

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution but it's getting parent thumbnail image, i like to get if product has selected in swatch option, that swatch option need to display.

example: if i select red colour, red colour swatch image need to display.

```
$productId = $_item->getProductId();
$objectManagerHere = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManagerHere->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imageHelper  = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize(80, 80)->getUrl();

<img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I have override `DefaultInvoice`

```
class DefaultInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice
{
    public function draw()
    {
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $item = $this->getItem();
        $pdf = $this->getPdf();
        $page = $this->getPage();
        $lines = [];


        // draw Product image
        $productImage = $this->getProductImage($item, $page);

        // draw Product name
        $lines[0] = [['text' => $this->string->split($item->getName(), 35, true, true), 'feed' => 35]];

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => $productImage,
            'is_image'  => 1,
            'feed'  => 200
        );

        // draw SKU
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $this->string->split($this->getSku($item), 17),
            'feed' => 370,
            'align' => 'right',
        ];

        // draw QTY
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => $item->getQty() * 1, 'feed' => 475, 'align' => 'right'];

        // draw item Prices
        $i = 0;
        $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
        $feedPrice = 425;
        $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 140;
        foreach ($prices as $priceData) {
            if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
                // draw Price label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
                // draw Subtotal label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedSubtotal, 'align' => 'right'];
                $i++;
            }
            // draw Price
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['price'],
                'feed' => $feedPrice,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            // draw Subtotal
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['subtotal'],
                'feed' => $feedSubtotal,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            $i++;
        }

        // draw Tax
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
            'feed' => 515,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];

        // custom options
        $options = $this->getItemOptions();
        if ($options) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                // draw options label
                $lines[][] = [
                    'text' => $this->string->split($this->filterManager->stripTags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                    'font' => 'italic',
                    'feed' => 35,
                ];

                if ($option['value']) {
                    if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                        $printValue = $option['print_value'];
                    } else {
                        $printValue = $this->filterManager->stripTags($option['value']);
                    }
                    $values = explode(', ', $printValue);
                    foreach ($values as $value) {
                        $lines[][] = ['text' => $this->string->split($value, 30, true, true), 'feed' => 40];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 20];

        $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true],1);

        $this->setPage($page);
    }


    /*
     * Return Value of custom attribute
     * */
    private function getProductImage($item,  &$page)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productId = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductId();
        $image = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

        if (!is_null($image)) {
            try{

                $imagePath = '/catalog/product/'.$image->getSmallImage();

                $filesystem = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
                $media_dir = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);

                if ($media_dir->isFile($imagePath)) {
                    return $media_dir->getAbsolutePath($imagePath);
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Which returns me PDF like this. (working on Image rotation :) )

[image]

**UPDATED**

> For variant based product - based on configure product's attribute
>   selection

```
class DefaultInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice
{
    public function draw()
    {
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $item = $this->getItem();
        $pdf = $this->getPdf();
        $page = $this->getPage();
        $lines = [];


        // draw Product image
        $productImage = $this->getProductImage($item, $page);

        // draw Product name
        $lines[0] = [['text' => $this->string->split($item->getName(), 35, true, true), 'feed' => 35]];

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => $productImage,
            'is_image'  => 1,
            'feed'  => 200
        );

        // draw SKU
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $this->string->split($this->getSku($item), 17),
            'feed' => 370,
            'align' => 'right',
        ];

        // draw QTY
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => $item->getQty() * 1, 'feed' => 475, 'align' => 'right'];

        // draw item Prices
        $i = 0;
        $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
        $feedPrice = 425;
        $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 140;
        foreach ($prices as $priceData) {
            if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
                // draw Price label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
                // draw Subtotal label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedSubtotal, 'align' => 'right'];
                $i++;
            }
            // draw Price
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['price'],
                'feed' => $feedPrice,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            // draw Subtotal
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['subtotal'],
                'feed' => $feedSubtotal,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            $i++;
        }

        // draw Tax
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
            'feed' => 515,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];

        // custom options
        $options = $this->getItemOptions();
        if ($options) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                // draw options label
                $lines[][] = [
                    'text' => $this->string->split($this->filterManager->stripTags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                    'font' => 'italic',
                    'feed' => 35,
                ];

                if ($option['value']) {
                    if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                        $printValue = $option['print_value'];
                    } else {
                        $printValue = $this->filterManager->stripTags($option['value']);
                    }
                    $values = explode(', ', $printValue);
                    foreach ($values as $value) {
                        $lines[][] = ['text' => $this->string->split($value, 30, true, true), 'feed' => 40];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 20];

        $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true],1);

        $this->setPage($page);
    }


    /*
     * Return Value of custom attribute
     * */
    private function getProductImage($item,  &$page)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productId = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductId();
        $data = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')->get($item->getSku());
        $image = $data->getImage();

        if (!is_null($image)) {
            try{

                $imagePath = '/catalog/product/'.$image;

                $filesystem = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
                $media_dir = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);

                if ($media_dir->isFile($imagePath)) {
                    return $media_dir->getAbsolutePath($imagePath);
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Here's simple product's image in Invoice based of variant selection of
>   configure product.

[image]

More References

**[Reference 1](https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-pdf-invoice-with-product-images-extension/)** , **[Reference 2](https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-pdf-invoice-image)** , **[Reference 3](https://community.magento.com/t5/Can-Magento-do/Product-images-in-emails-Magento2-1/td-p/81070)**

Answer (score 0):

You can replace following line in your code

```
$product = $objectManagerHere->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
```

With following line

```
$product = $objectManagerHere->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')->get($_item->getSku());
```

With this, you can get appropriate simple product of configurable product.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with `cart_page_product_thumbnail` instead of `product_thumbnail_image` in your get product image code.

Your code should be like this.

```
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize(80, 80)->getUrl();
```

I have used the above code to display product image in the Email template and it is working fine with configurable products. and I think it also works for the invoice email template.

I have also seen so many users use `cart_page_product_thumbnail` please check below reference link.

- [Product image in-new order email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147762/magento-2-product-image-in-new-order-email)
- [Display product image in sales order view-page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106556/how-to-display-product-image-in-sales-order-view-page)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

So, you have to follow this Steps to Display Product Image in Invoice Pdf Attachment:

1. Create This File :   **app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Model/Magento/Sales/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Magento\Sales\Order\Pdf;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
    /* Add table head */
       $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
       $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
       $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
       $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
       $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
    $this->y -= 10;
       $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));
    //columns headers
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Product Image'), 'feed' => 200]; // Add this line 
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 370, 'align' => 'right'];
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 475, 'align' => 'right'];
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 425, 'align' => 'right'];
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 515, 'align' => 'right'];
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];
    $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];
       $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
       $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
    $this->y -= 20;
    }
            /**
    * Return PDF document
    *
    * @param array|Collection $invoices
    * @return \Zend_Pdf
    */
    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
            $this->_beforeGetPdf();
      $this->_initRenderer('invoice');
    
    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
       $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
       $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
               $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
               $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
        }
        $page = $this->newPage();
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        /* Add image */
           $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add address */
           $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add head */
          $this->insertOrder(
            $page,
               $order,
               $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                   self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                   \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                   $order->getStoreId()
            )
        );
        /* Add document text and number */
           $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
        /* Add table */
           $this->_drawHeader($page);
        /* Add body */
        foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                   continue;
            }
            /* Draw item */
               $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
            $page = end($pdf->pages);
        }
        /* Add totals */
           $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
               $this->_localeResolver->revert();
        }
    }
       $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
    }
    
    public function drawLineBlocks(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page, array $draw, array $pageSettings = [], $flag = 0)
    {
      foreach ($draw as $itemsProp) {
        if (!isset($itemsProp['lines']) || !is_array($itemsProp['lines'])) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                   __('We don\'t recognize the draw line data. Please define the "lines" array.')
            );
        }
        $lines = $itemsProp['lines'];
        $height = isset($itemsProp['height']) ? $itemsProp['height'] : 10;
        if (empty($itemsProp['shift'])) {
            $shift = 0;
               foreach ($lines as $line) {
                   $maxHeight = 0;
                   foreach ($line as $column) {
                       $lineSpacing = !empty($column['height']) ? $column['height'] : $height;
                       if (!is_array($column['text'])) {
                           $column['text'] = [$column['text']];
                       }
                       $top = 0;
                       foreach ($column['text'] as $part) {
                        $top += $lineSpacing;
                       }
                       $maxHeight = $top > $maxHeight ? $top : $maxHeight;
                }
                   $shift += $maxHeight;
            }
               $itemsProp['shift'] = $shift;
        }
        if ($this->y - $itemsProp['shift'] < 15) { $page = $this->newPage($pageSettings);
        }
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
               $maxHeight = 0;
            $i = 0;
             if (($this->y - 100) < 15) { $page = $this->newPage($pageSettings);
            }
               foreach ($line as $column) {
                   if($i == 1 && $flag){
                       $i++;
                       if(array_key_exists('is_image', $column) && !is_null($column['text'])){
                           $image = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($column['text']);
                           $feed = $column['feed'];
                           $page->drawImage($image, $feed, $this->y, $feed+70, $this->y-80);
                           $maxHeight = 100;
                       }
                       continue 1;
                }
                   $i++;
                   $fontSize = empty($column['font_size']) ? 10 : $column['font_size'];
                if (!empty($column['font_file'])) {
                       $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath($column['font_file']);
                       $page->setFont($font, $fontSize);
                } else {
                       $fontStyle = empty($column['font']) ? 'regular' : $column['font'];
                       switch ($fontStyle) {
                           case 'bold':
                            $font = $this->_setFontBold($page, $fontSize);
                            break;
                           case 'italic':
                            $font = $this->_setFontItalic($page, $fontSize);
                            break;
                         default:
                            $font = $this->_setFontRegular($page, $fontSize);
                            break;
                       }
                }
                if (!is_array($column['text'])) {
                       $column['text'] = [$column['text']];
                }
                   $lineSpacing = !empty($column['height']) ? $column['height'] : $height;
                   $top = 0;
                   foreach ($column['text'] as $part) {
                       if ($this->y - $lineSpacing < 15) { $page = $this->newPage($pageSettings);
                       }
                       $feed = $column['feed'];
                       $textAlign = empty($column['align']) ? 'left' : $column['align'];
                       $width = empty($column['width']) ? 0 : $column['width'];
                       switch ($textAlign) {
                           case 'right':
                            if ($width) {
                                $feed = $this->getAlignRight($part, $feed, $width, $font, $fontSize);
                            } else {
                                $feed = $feed - $this->widthForStringUsingFontSize($part, $font, $fontSize);
                            }
                            break;
                           case 'center':
                            if ($width) {
                                $feed = $this->getAlignCenter($part, $feed, $width, $font, $fontSize);
                            }
                            break;
                           default:
                            break;
                       }
                       $page->drawText($part, $feed, $this->y - $top, 'UTF-8');
                       $top += $lineSpacing;
                }
                   //$maxHeight = 100;
                   $maxHeight = $top > $maxHeight ? $top : $maxHeight;
            }
               $this->y -= $maxHeight;
        }
    }
    return $page;
    }
}
```

2. Responsible Vendor File For Invoice Pdf Product Data :

**vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php**

3. Override in your custom module like this :

**Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Magento\Sales\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice.php**

4. Define in DI file [di.xml] :

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" type="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Magento\Sales\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice"/>
```

Now you Need to add some code in **draw()** function and make custom **getProductImage()** function in your Custom DefaultInvoice.php file

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Magento\Sales\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice;

use Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Magento\Sales\Order\Pdf\Invoice;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


class DefaultInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice
{
    public function draw()
    {
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    $item = $this->getItem();
    $pdf = $this->getPdf();
    $page = $this->getPage();
    $lines = [];

    // draw Product image         // Step 1 
    $productImage = $this->getProductImage($item, $page);
    

    // draw Product name
    $lines[0] = [['text' => $this->string->split($item->getName(), 35, true, true), 'feed' => 35]];

    // draw Product image                  // Step 2
    $lines[0][] = array(
    'text' => '',
    'feed' => 35,
    'is_image' => true,
    'image' => $productImage,
    );
    // draw SKU
    $lines[0][] = [
        'text' => $this->string->split($this->getSku($item), 17),
        'feed' => 370,
        'align' => 'right',
    ];
    // draw QTY
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => $item->getQty() * 1, 'feed' => 475, 'align' => 'right'];
    // draw item Prices
    $i = 0;
    $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
    $feedPrice = 425;
    $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 140;
    foreach ($prices as $priceData) {
        if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
            // draw Price label
               $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
            // draw Subtotal label
               $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedSubtotal, 'align' => 'right'];
               $i++;
        }
        // draw Price
           $lines[$i][] = [
            'text' => $priceData['price'],
            'feed' => $feedPrice,
            'font' => 'bold',
               'align' => 'right',
        ];
        // draw Subtotal
           $lines[$i][] = [
            'text' => $priceData['subtotal'],
            'feed' => $feedSubtotal,
            'font' => 'bold',
               'align' => 'right',
        ];
        $i++;
    }
    // draw Tax
    $lines[0][] = [
        'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
        'feed' => 515,
        'font' => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right',
    ];
    // custom options
    $options = $this->getItemOptions();
    if ($options) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            // draw options label
               $lines[][] = [
                   'text' => $this->string->split($this->filterManager->stripTags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                   'font' => 'italic',
                   'feed' => 35,
            ];
            if ($option['value']) {
                if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                       $printValue = $option['print_value'];
                } else {
                       $printValue = $this->filterManager->stripTags($option['value']);
                }
                   $values = explode(', ', $printValue);
                   foreach ($values as $value) {
                       $lines[][] = ['text' => $this->string->split($value, 30, true, true), 'feed' => 40];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 20];
    
    $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true],1);
    
       $this->setPage($page);
    }

    /*
    * Return Value of custom attribute       // Step 3
    * */
    private function getProductImage($item, &$page)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productId = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductId();
        $image = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId)->getSmallImage();
        if ($image) {
            try {
                $mediaDirectory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $imagePath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('/catalog/product' . $image);
                if ($mediaDirectory->isFile($imagePath)) {
                    $image = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($imagePath);
                    
                    $imageWidth = 50; // set image width to 50 pixels
                    $imageHeight = 50; // set image height to 50 pixels
                    $top = 450;
                    $left = 30;
                    $bottom = $top - $imageHeight;
                    $right = $left + $imageWidth;
                    $page->drawImage($image, $left, $bottom, $right, $top);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now Run All the Required Terminal Commands and check Invoice Pdf Attachment :

**- Admin Login**
**- Go to Sales -> Invoices -> View -> Send Email**
**- Check Customer Email**

**Before :**

[image]

**After :**

[image]

**I hope it helps!**